# How to hide date in Date picker

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I am using the below code to hide Date in Date picker. This code works fine for Android Marshmallow, Lollipop versions. But it crashes when I try it in Android Nougat device.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    MyDatePickerDialog myDatePickerDialog = new MyDatePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, onDateSetListener, y, m, d);
    myDatePickerDialog.setPermanentTitle("Date Picker");
    ((ViewGroup) myDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker())
            .findViewById(
                    Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id",
                            "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    DatePicker datePicker = myDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker();              
    datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
    datePicker.setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    return myDatePickerDialog;
}
```

The crash is found in the following code.

```
 ((ViewGroup) myDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker())
     .findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id",
          "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```